# Egg YOLK replacement?

Tags: substitutions, bread, eggs, yolk

I am making an old family recipe for Easter Bread, but I would like to make a vegan version of it for a friend.

The non vegan ingredients that the recipe calls for are:

milk (substituting with almond milk)

butter (substituting with Earth Balance)

3 egg yolks

Help!! I can not think or find a good alternative to just 3 egg yolks. I am questioning the consistency of a lot of the suggestions I have found online.

Thank you in advance for all suggestions and ideas!

Comment: Hmmm.  Yolks are fat and protein and binding agents... serve a lot of jobs.  Hope someone with experience can find the right combination!

Comment: @rumtscho : the 'duplicate' is about whole eggs, not egg yolks.

Comment: @Joe thank you for catching that, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: How are you using the yolks?  Is it in the dough, or an egg wash?  For quick breads, I've used mashed bananas, but I don't know if it'd work for a yeast bread.   I found https://www.mydarlingvegan.com/replacing-eggs/ , which mentions soaking raw cashews and blending them.  See also https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/41739/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/27580/67

Comment: If you add the full recipe; then it would be easier to figure out the usage of egg yolks, thus the suggestions for replacements will be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In an article I with a very quick google search found [here](https://www.mydarlingvegan.com/replacing-eggs/), it seems that you can

> blend 1 tablespoon of flax or chia seeds with 3 tablespoons of water until mixture is thick and creamy.

However, I suspect that this would add a gritty texture that would be unpleasant in easter sweet breads. You would probably find that a full-fat yogurt is a good alternative, having both protein and fats.

I also found [this](http://www.yummysmells.ca/2014/03/vegan-egg-yolk-substitute.html) article, which uses chickpea flour, flour (wheat, rice, sorghum), water and oil.

Comment: The flax/chia substitution is for whole eggs, not egg yolks only as asked for here.

Comment: Yes indeed, however considering that the white is largely water (88%) and protein (11%), you could consider the white as a replacement for some of the liquid component and add a bit more oil to substitute for the yolk (~15% protein, ~35% lipids, ~50% water). The addition of extra protein from the white may play a role in the bread rise, but having substituted whole egg for yolk in many recipes I don't think whole egg substitutes would be a problem with a bit of experimentation.